# Why am i getting " org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of" although the string isn't empty?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am getting response of a server, when i log the response body i get the access_token right, but when i try to convert it to a jsonObject it says the string is empty!

```
   apiInterface.Login(Email,Pass).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                try {
                    Log.d("PONSEMONSE",response.body().string());
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    Log.d("LONO",jsonObject.getString("access_token"));
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
              /*  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);*/

            }
        }
```

The first log output ("PONSEMONSE"):

```
04-15 14:25:55.019 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom D/PONSEMONSE: {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNodWJha3kuMDA3QHlhaG9vLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6Mywicm9sZSI6IlNUVURFTlQiLCJ2ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTYxODQ4OTU1NiwiZXhwIjoxNjE4NTc1OTU2fQ.bZT-GOQiixLH0ZqdmRnh1khU6JMfp41RvjW0YrjK9IY"}
```

the error:

```
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: 
End of input at character 0 of 
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
  04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
com.example.lambdaroom.LoginActivity$2.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:90)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at    
retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.
run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
04-15 14:25:55.029 14235-14235/com.example.lambdaroom W/System.err:     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included the import statement, so we can't be 100% sure.  However it looks like the `ResponseBody` that you are using is actually `okhttp.okhttp3.ResponseBody`.  If so, the okhttp documentation states that:

- the body can only be consumed once, and
- the `string()` method that consumes the body.

The reasoning behind this behavior is that it means that `ResponseBody` is not forced to buffer the entire response somewhere (e.g. in memory) just in case it is needed.  Considering that the response *could* be extremely large, this is a good thing in general.

Reference:

- [okhttp / okhttp3 / ResponseBody](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/)

Comment: yes correct i have answered myself almost as just as i posted the question

Comment: I am aware of that. The purpose of my answer was to provide *more* information for *other people* with the same problem as you.  The real goal of StackOverflow is not to solve >your< programming problem.  It is to build a resource to help solve everybody's programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reponse.body.string() can be called only once otherwise it's empty :/